# NGINX: Each domain shares multiple ssl_certificate's

Tags: ssl, nginx

Is it possible to have each domain use multiple ssl certificates?  When I google for this, [the top result is an article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04) on how to have two ssl_certificates for two domains, but each domain is tied to one `ssl_certificate`.  Is there a way to have each tied to multiple certificates?  The way I'd want it to work is to try with the first ssl certificate and if it fails, try with the second, and if that didn't work, fallback to other options.  We attempted this using techniques from the article, but when we did nginx gave us this warning:

```
2016/12/30 20:31:41 [warn] 186#186: conflicting server name "domain1" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "domain1" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
2016/12/30 20:31:41 [warn] 186#186: conflicting server name "domain2" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "domain2" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
```

Why do we want to do this? The `ssl_certificate` refers to a file that allows access to one inbound domain, and we also want the nginx to allow access from another domain.  I don't know much about ssl/certificates.  Is there an easy way to modify the `ssl_certificate` to allow multiple domains?  That would be an alternative solution to this problem.

Comment: @OliverHader I edited my question.  After re-reading it I don't think it was clear.  Does your reply still apply?

Comment: Thanks for updating, I modified my comment at the same time it seems... Anyway, could you please post your current configuration to see how domain1 and domain2 relate to each other currently. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a single leaf certificate served inside the TLS handshake. If the validation of this certificate fails the handshake will fail. While many browsers will retry with a lower protocol TLS version as a fallback against broken servers this is not intended to be used to serve different certificates. Apart from that almost no TLS implementations outside browsers implement this fallback.

Thus servers don't support serving multiple leaf certificates within a single host configuration. They usually do support having different certificates for different subdomains and it is also possible to have different servers for the same domain using different certificates (i.e. different IP address or port). It is also possible in newer servers that a single configuration allows both RSA and ECC certificates (i.e. ECDSA authentication) but in this case the server will simply pick the relevant certificate based on which ciphers the client supports and will still send only a single leaf certificate.

Comment: The signature of a certificate refers to the web of trust part only. This way, is possible to have different certificates for one domain name from different (official) certificate authorities. However, the important fact is, that for each connection only one certificate can be used for TLS encryption - like you mentioned.

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply.  What about this: Could I have one ssl_certificate that handles two domains?

Comment: @DanielKaplan: yes, you could use a single certificate which covers multiple names. This is actually very common. Look for [wildcard certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) or [SAN certificates](https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm).